# How to apply security restriction on versions of items in Sitecore CMS?

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to apply security restrictions on older version of items?
 I would like to restrict read access to previous versions of item for particular roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set security on specific versions.
If you change it for one version of an item, it will be changed for all versions of that item.
I wonder in which case this could be useful though.

Comment: Scenario: The organization want to keep versions of content item but will ensure different other cases like: Only latest version is available to for for most of the editors, but some other Roles can read the previous version… Senior editors can view (read the content) all versions of the content item.

Answer (score 1):

The security field is 'shared' across versions, meaning it's value it always the same across all versions of the item.

This is one of Sitecore's default fields, so I'd suggest not to change it.

However if you really want to, you can go to */sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Security* and untick the box on the right called 'Shared' for the field '__Security'.

Then you can go to each item and manually change the security settings for each version.

Disclaimer: I have no idea what effect this could have on security applications, so I don't know if the security editor would stop working, or if Sitecore in general would start to slow. Either way, I would advise against doing this, as I'm not sure it's recommended.

Comment: I think it will not have any effect. The 'shared' field is used for sharing across language versions and not across content versions. I expected the 'unversioned' checkbox to be set for __Security, but it's not. So i guess there is something else in Sitecore's process that takes care of sharing the security field across all versions.

Comment: Shared is a superset of unversioned. A shared field is always unversioned. I.e. you can't share a field across languages without sharing it across versions. I think unsharing the security field would probably have disastrous consequences, not least for the Sitecore security editor and Sitecore security viewer.